# Ionic Compounds

Tags: metal, ionic-compounds

Do elements share chemical or physical properties in an ionic compound?
I mean if a metal would have an ionic compound with a nonmetal would the compound have physical properties of the metal and chemical properties of the nonmetal or the opposite?

P.s. I said "traits" in my comment... I meant properties

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit what you are meaning? E.g. take table salt which is a ionic compound of sodium (a metal, solid) and chlorine (nonmetal, a gas).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. Your question as written is very hard to follow and I (and at least one person in the comments) cannot make sense of it. Could you try expanding the question, maybe giving some examples? As it stands, I believe it will be closed. Best of luck!

Comment: @aventurin Well let's say a metalloid would do a compound with a metal. Metalloids have the physical traits of a metal (by physical traits I mean like conductivity) and chemical traits of a nonmetal (by chemical traits I mean if it would lose electrons in a compound or get one)
If it does a compound with a metal would the compound have physical traits of a metal or a nonmetal? And what about chemical traits?
P.s. Both would be solid

Comment: What you talkin' 'bout, Willis?

Comment: @IvanNeretin No? Would you explain a bit please?

Comment: Ions do not have properties of the neutral atom, so the comparison of properties that the OP wants here doesn't make sense.

Comment: _sigh_  Asking in the way you do now doesn't make real sense. Compounds have  little to nothing in common with the elements from which are made. One could say, the more complicated they are, the less, but even this isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

No. When elements form compounds, the physical and chemical properties of this new compound are *unique* to this compound; explicitly, they are different from all elements a compound is made up of and there is no way to derive one from the other.

Note that sometimes there are different compounds made from the same elements such as iron(II) chloride and iron(III) chloride. Or maybe even more obvious: tin(IV) chloride (a liquid) and tin(II) chloride (an ionic solid). And finally note that even elements have different modifications with different physical and chemical properties such as phosphorus (white, red, purple, black) or carbon (graphite or diamond).